# Why sizeof(x++) does not increment the variable x value

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x = 99;
    int y = sizeof(x++);
    printf("x is %d", x);
}
```

The result of above program is:

> x is 99

Why ? Can anyone tell why `x` is not incremented in *sizeof operator*.