# Is Deferencing an Uninitialized Pointer in sizeof Legal?

Tags: c

Given the following code, is it legal in C?
(C89, C99, and so on?)

```
DATA_STRUCT *ptr;

ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) + 400);

memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(*ptr)); // clearing only the structure itself (not the 400 additional bytes).
```

I'm aware of VLA and sizeof being evaluated at run-time, but for all other cases, is it always at compile-time?

---

EDIT:
From the answers I see this may be caused by:

1. A compiler bug
2. A heap corruption

1 seems sorta unlikely, so I'm leaning towards 2.
Either way, this needs to be further investigated.

Comment: This was just asked [why sizeof(x++) does not increment the variable x value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995680/why-sizeofx-does-not-increment-the-variable-x-value), and the answer is the same, it is unevaluated.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY well the last sentence asks `I'm aware of VLA and sizeof being evaluated at run-time, but for all other cases, is it always at compile-time?` which is basically the same question.

Comment: The call to malloc is wrong, malloc takes one parameter only. But `sizeof(x)` will never evaluate x, so your code is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is legal.  The parentheses around `*ptr` aren't necessary, though.

Comment: thanks, I also thought so. But we're seeing a bug right now that the program crashes at this line (changing *ptr to DATA_STRUCT) solves the problem). And it's certainly not a VLA. This is weird... Needs further investigation on our part... maybe somewhere else in the code is blowing up...

Comment: ... Or your compiler is nonstandard, possibly.

Comment: @BeyondSora: Which "this line"? The malloc or the memset? Did you leave out the line where you check if the malloc returns NULL, or is it not there?

Comment: @BeyondSora: I seriously doubt that changing `sizeof(*ptr)` to `sizeof(DATA_STRUCT)` solved the problem. Recompiling may have caused *different* randomish behavior to occur. If your program crashes on a call to `malloc`, it's probably because something that executed previously corrupted the heap. Run the program under `valgrind` if possible. (And since your real problem is that your program crashes, you probably should have asked about that rather than about the legality of `sizeof(*ptr)`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks. This question was probably phrased in a wrong way. I didn't doubt that sizeof(*ptr) was the problem and suspected something else was going on. But since the bug is temporarily "suppressed" I thought to ask on StackOverflow to clarify the legality of sizeof(*ptr) before the team proceeds to root cause further.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid. `sizeof` operator does not evaluate its operand.